# Is it ok to use multiple pseudo-elements in css?

Tags: css, pseudo-element, pseudo-class

I want to make a menu where each item is separated with a ·. To achieve this I use

```
menu li:before {
    content: "· ";
}
```

This is swell, but it generates a dot before the first item as well. Therefore, i would like to use `:first-child` pseudo-class as well. Can I do this?

Comment: works fine with modern browser. I have once used hover & after class. And it woked.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Sure you can - http://jsfiddle.net/WQBxk/

```
p:before {
    content: "BEFORE ";
    display: block;
}

p:first-child:before {
    content: "1ST";
    display: block
}
​
```

The bad - it won't work in IE7 and below. Not because of the multiple pseudo selectors, but because of non-supported `:before` - http://kimblim.dk/css-tests/selectors/

Just tested in IE8 - works well.

Comment: You can use multiple pseudo-classes, but you cannot use multiple pseudo-elements. This is where the distinction between the two becomes important (and the use of the term "pseudo-selectors" can cause potential confusion).

Comment: Hey, I was was going to ask a question similar to this, but then I saw this question to use multiple pseudo-classes so I decided to ask my question in these comments.  [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/NathanielSantley/nLnjbf50/6/) is my fiddle.  I want it to display "Invalid email!" in red if it is indeed an invalid email and "Valid email!" in green if it is a valid email.  Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/surendraVsingh/zRrLF/

```
<ul>
<li>lorem</li>
<li>lorem</li>
<li>lorem</li>
<li>lorem</li>
<li>lorem</li>
<li>lorem</li>

</ul>​
```

**CSS:**

```
li:before{content:'. ';}
li:first-child:before{content:'@ ';}
```

Answer (score -2):

Of course you can use pseudo classes.They are quite well supported from IE8 and up.You can check the compatibility of any pseudoclass you are going to use here http://caniuse.com/#search=after

If you don't want a dot just use empty commas in content and then display:block and also specify height and width.

```
menu li:before {
    content: "";

    display:block;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background:red;

}
```