# Attach current range number directly above HTML range slider thumb

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

Is there a native way to attach the current range value directly above the current position of the HTML range thumb (i.e. a value that chases the current thumb position)? I currently have a simple formula to update position by multiplying the percentage of the current value over the total value by the width of the slider:

```
updatePosition() {
  const { currentValue, rangeMax, rangeMin } = this.props;
  const sliderWidth = document.getElementsByClassName(className)[0].clientWidth;
  const newPosition = (currentValue - rangeMin) / (rangeMax - rangeMin);
  const updatedPosition = (sliderWidth * newPosition) - 30; // subtracting 30 to help align over slider thumb

  this.setState({ updatedPosition });
}
```

and then passing that `"updatedPosition"` value in as the `"left"` attribute of the `div` containing the value via inline styling.

It currently works, but there is sometimes a little bit of a lag to it, especially in IE, so I was wondering if there is a more precise way that I can obtain/update the value's position. Would prefer to not use a package. Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23865523/how-to-show-the-value-of-range-slider-on-the-thumb-of-the-slider

Answer (score 2):

[This is the code](https://codepen.io/yannicvanveen/pen/HtvbI) that I ended up using (not my code). Works pretty well for what I need it to do. I obviously changed it slightly to make it specific to React, but otherwise pretty much used it as is.

```
$('input[type="range"]').on('input', function() {

  var control = $(this),
    controlMin = control.attr('min'),
    controlMax = control.attr('max'),
    controlVal = control.val(),
    controlThumbWidth = control.data('thumbwidth');

  var range = controlMax - controlMin;

  var position = ((controlVal - controlMin) / range) * 100;
  var positionOffset = Math.round(controlThumbWidth * position / 100) - (controlThumbWidth / 2);
  var output = control.next('output');

  output
    .css('left', 'calc(' + position + '% - ' + positionOffset + 'px)')
    .text(controlVal);

});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should adapt your function to use `getBoundingClientRect()`.  This function returns an object with window coords as properties.

```
var pos = element.getBoundingClientRect();
console.log(pos.top)
```

Logs the Y-coordinate for the top element edge.

A great reference/explanation can be found at http://javascript.info/coordinates.