# How to add text to slider thumb using input type range?

Tags: html, css

I try to make an thumb with content inside but it's not working and i dont know why it's not working . Any one know to add content to thumb in chrome ?

here is my css

```
input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb::after {
  content: 'test';
  color: red;
}

input[type='range'] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: var(--theme-special-dark);
  outline: none;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: opacity 0.2s;
  position: relative;
}

input[type='range']::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 40px;
  height: 38px;
  background: var(--theme-text-black);
  cursor: pointer;
  position: relative;
}

input[type='range']::before {
  content: 'HT In Bay';
  color: black;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 400;
  left: 140px;
  top: 7px;
}
```

Comment: Consider reading this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23865523/how-to-show-the-value-of-range-slider-on-the-thumb-of-the-slider

Comment: @ismi i saw but maybe it's no way to add content using before or after .... only the way is change background image ..

Comment: you can use a wrapper and inside the wrapper you can use input range and a span tag. just hide the thumb and use the span tag as a thumb, you can get better performance this way.